# Upper bound for $(AB-BA)x$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, matrix-calculus

Given matrices $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$where matrix $A$ is a diagonal matrix and $B$ is an upper triangular matrix. I'm looking for an upper bound for the expression
\begin{align*}
(AB-BA),
\end{align*}
in the form of i.e.
\begin{align*}
\lVert(AB-BA)\rVert_2\leq\lVert f(A)\rVert_2\cdot\lVert g(B)\rVert_2.
\end{align*}
My intent is to create an upper bound which seperates the effect of $A$ and $ B$. We assume that:
\begin{align*}
A\neq c\cdot I,\quad c\in\mathbb{R}
\end{align*}
But, ideally, the upper-bound should reflect it when this property is the case. For instance we can define a rough upper bound:
\begin{align*}
\lVert(AB-BA)\rVert_2\leq(2\lVert A\rVert_2\lVert B\rVert_2).
\end{align*}
But it doesn't reflect the scenario where $A=c\cdot I$ holds (i.e. AB-BA=0). Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!